# creating button like icons

Tags: css

i want to add an icon on my web page and i want my icon to look big buttons with an image inside them,i have a `largebut_hover.png` , `largebut.png` and `icon.png` ,the icon image is covered by the light grey `largebut.png` and when hovering the `largebut_hover.png` appears to be specific i came across a site with nice buttons like icons like this [icons like these ones here](http://tecdiary.net/demo/invoice-manager/index.php?module=home)

but i do not know how i can do it for example i can only manage to do this

```
<ul class="dash">                       
            <li>
            <a href="#" title="Users" class="tip" data-placement="bottom">
            <img src="images/icons/users.png" alt="" />
            <span>Users</span>
            </a>
            </li>
            </ul>
```

any ideas how i can make them??i know it has to do with the css mainly but im stack,i would love to learn how to do it though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want that icons, and some fancy and ready-to-use css layouts you could use [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#buttons)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to create buttons like this ones?

[image]

And then when you hover it it gets a `light grey colour` ? Those buttons have been made using CSS and not `largebut.png` like you said.

Here is the example:

[image]

If you are looking to make that, then you it will not be that hard, I can tell you that. Easy way to do it is applying CSS classes like `.btn-primary:hover {...}` where `...` is the code for the colours and all stuff you want to do it.

Also, you could read their CSS code, but i am not sure if you are familiar with it, so that would leave you more confused. I think the best way for you to start would be the [W3 School](http://www.w3schools.com/).